# Bigquery throwing "Unexpected" error

Tags: google-bigquery

Can someone from the BigQuery group help me debug this problem. I'm trying to run a query and it throws "Unexpected error" after running for more than 6000 seconds.

Job id: job_3MHZtho6xz0FuY5niz4P3VZqwRI.

or throws a 
"Connection Error" - job id: job_Aqo7H8KA0EYUHCVBBLCMyYSwJ5I

I can post the query here but I doubt it will help anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked up the job on the BigQuery backend, and essentially, your query timed out. From the job statistics, it looks, however, like you've got a join explosion. You're joining a 300 million row table against a million row table, but some of the keys in the million row table are not unique, which means that JOIN semantics will generate multiple output rows.

It looks like you're query is going to generate many *billion* rows (or even trillions if it completes) of results. Is that intentional?

Comment: Are these limits documented somewhere?